# Developing JSON API for a Carpool Engine

Tags: interfaces, api

I am developing a new set of API methods for carpooling/cab booking, so if a developer needs to develop an app or webportal for carpooling, he can call my JSON API. Basically making it easy for developers.

My API current has:

- `AddVehicle`
- `AddJourney`
- `SearchJourney`
- `SubscribeToThisJourney(journey)`
- `SubscriberList(journey)` to get list of people who have subscribed for this journey
- `AcceptSubscription(subscriber)`
- `AcceptedSubcriberList`
- `SubscriberList` to get list of providers I have subscribed to

I need help with replacing subscriber with something else. It's difficult to remember, and confusing when you see 3 methods that mean very different things: `SubscriberList`, `SubscribedToThisJourneyList` and `AcceptedSubscriberList`. Confusing to remember.

- One is a list of who I have subscribed to
- Who has subscribed to me
- Whose subscription I have accepted

How can I name these methods to make them easier to understand and remember?

Comment: Please note, I have been migrated from ux.stackexchange.com. I hope to get feedback from the developers out there.

Comment: So your question is? We can probably guess it, but it's a good idea to make it explicit in the text of the question.

Comment: I hope its clearer now.

Comment: I hope I didn't change your meaning with my edit, but your use of the term API was a little off. Questions for you: `SubscriberList` and `AcceptedSubscriberList` are in your initial list, but `SubscribedToThisJourneyList` is not; is there a typo in there somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some suggestions for names for the three methods that you list as needing attention:

- *One is a list of who I have subscribed to* - based on your earlier description for `SubscriberList`, I assume by 'who' you mean which providers, so a clearer version might be: **`ProvidersSubscribedTo(user)`**
- *Who has subscribed to me* - assuming this is meant to list the subscribers who I, as a Provider, have not yet accepted: **`PendingSubscribers(provider)`**
- *Whose subscription I have accepted*  - **`AcceptedSubscribers(provider)`**

I've used parameters to indicate the context of the method call, so depending on how the calls are made, they might not be required.

Comment: Oh man, my test looks so neat now. PendingSubscribers, For loop, acceptSubscription, AcceptedSubscribers. This is what I am talking about.

Answer (score 1):

I do not see a problem with your chosen names, as the verb `subscribe` and the noun `subscriber` have very different (but rightly) related meanings in English.

Proper documentation is going to be key here.

Comment: I agree, proper documentation is needed.